# Sealing flip-top bottles with wax

Tags: bottling, mead, oxidation

I just started brewing a batch of mead (non-carbonated) and plan to bottle it in 1 L and 500 mL swing-top bottles.

Is there any advantage or disadvantage to sealing the swing-tops by dipping them in melted wax to further prevent oxidation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wax dip gives an added layer of protection and look great too.

The most functional part of a wax dip is to **prevent crimp caps from rust** from environment. Especially for beverages that will age in the bottle.

Wax doesn't prevent oxygen with caps, if the cap breaches the wax breaks too. If corking, then wax functions as the oxygen barrier.

Mtyh: Wax allows you to store beer on its side for aging. This is only true for corked bottles, to keep the cork wet and sealed. Wax on corked bottles allows vertical storage without o2 contact. Cap only bottles should never be stored on their side with or without wax.

Wax will prevent the lip crud from turning into something harmful. That little bit of beer that gets trapped in the outside crimps. Sometimes can't always be rinsed out. Wax seals it up.

In your case with swing tops. The sealing portion is glass and rubber so there's no rust issues. **Imo wax in this case will give no benifiet other than cosmetic**, and make for a mess to remove all the wax from the hinge for next use.

Comment: I was actually wondering if there was any benefit, but I had not thought about how hard it would be to clean for reuse. Thanks. I think I'll skip it. I am also looking at Zorks with regular 750 mL wine bottles.

Comment: It should probably be noted that there's a strong debate on whether to age beer on its side or standing up, and there are some cork-topped bottles whose brewers recommend standing up, but do not wax their corks.

Comment: @bendl I believe the non waxed examples use non permeable synthetic corks. Or have cork and crimp cap. Such as most export lambics.

Comment: Agreed about the synthetic corks. I have no evidence to the contrary. My main point was to alert a newcomer that there is a debate on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no real advantage in dipping swing tops into molten wax before sealing. More to the point little bits of wax from the top might find their way into the mead. Being wax they tend to float and make presentation "less than optimal".
Unfiltered/unpasteurised/unsterilised mead (like wine) will age well in a normally sealed bottle.